# autoplay is not working in jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have this jquery slider from some author. I do have autoplay feature built in. But when I am using it in my website the jquery sliders are not changing on autoplay. Following is the code for that

According to the documentation to make the slide autoplay you need to put the below code into your main index HTML file. But even after adding this code the slides autoplay is not working. And no error is reported in the console.

I've put this code after the script tag which adds slider.js to the HTML.

code in index.html

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#slider').rbtSlider({
        height: '500px',
        'dots': true,
        'arrows': true,
        'auto': 1
    });
});
</script>
```

The slider html code

```
 <div class="slider" id="slider">
    <div class="slItems">
        <div class="slItem">
            <div class="slText">
                <p>
                    some content
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slItem">
            <div class="slText">
                <p>
                    some content
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the slider.js code

```
jQuery.fn.rbtSlider = function(opt){
        return this.each(function() {
            var slider = $(this);
            if (opt.height) slider.css('height', opt.height);
            slider.find('.slItem').first().addClass('active');
            if (opt.dots) {
                var count = slider.find('.slItem').length;
                slider.append(
                    $('<div/>', {
                        class: 'slDots',
                        html: $('<div/>', {
                            class: 'slDotsSingle active'
                        })
                    })                                  
                );
                for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                    slider.find('.slDotsSingle.active').clone().removeClass('active').appendTo($(this).find('.slDots'));    
                }
                slider.find('.slDotsSingle').on('click', function(){
                    curIndex = $(this).parents('.slDots').find('.active').removeClass('active').index() + 1;
                    index = $(this).addClass('active').index() + 1;
                    if (index != curIndex) {
                        if (index > curIndex) nav('next', index);
                        else nav('prev', index);
                    }
                });
            }
            if (opt.arrows) {
                slider.append(
                    $('<div/>', {
                        class: 'ctrlPrev',
                        html: '&lsaquo;'
                    }).on('click', function(){
                        nav('prev');
                    })
                ).append(
                    $('<div/>', {
                        class: 'ctrlNext',
                        html: '&rsaquo;'
                    }).on('click', function(){
                        nav('next');
                    })
                );
            }
            if (opt.auto) {
                var time = setInterval(function(){nav('next')}, opt.auto * 1000);
                slider.on('mouseover', function() {
                    clearInterval(time);
                }).on('mouseleave', function() {
                    time = setInterval(function(){nav('next')}, opt.auto * 1000);
                });
            }

            function nav(side, index) {
                if (index) {
                    nextItem = slider.find('.slItem').eq(index - 1);
                } else {
                    if (side == 'prev') {
                        if (slider.find('.slItem.active').prev().length) nextItem = slider.find('.slItem.active').prev();  
                        else nextItem = slider.find('.slItem').last();
                    } else {
                        if (slider.find('.slItem.active').next().length) nextItem = slider.find('.slItem.active').next();
                        else nextItem = slider.find('.slItem').first();
                    }    
                    slider.find('.slDots > .active').removeClass('active').parent().find('.slDotsSingle').eq(nextItem.index()).addClass('active');
                }
                nextItem.addClass(side + 'Item').delay(50).queue(function(){
                    slider.find('.slItems > .active').addClass(side).delay(700).queue(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass(side +' active').dequeue();
                    });

                    $(this).addClass(side).delay(700).queue(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass(side + ' ' + side + 'Item').addClass('active').clearQueue();
                    });

                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Did you try shifting your script codes to below your </BODY> tag?

Comment: yes I did but still not working

Comment: have you got some error in your console?

Comment: no error is shown in console

Comment: Did you add the slider CSS, slider Javascript and Jquery?

Comment: yes I did. Swipe is working on clicking on button

Comment: Is your mouse cursor over the slider, by any chance? The code says that if the mouse cursor is hovering over the slider, it will "pause" the autoplay feature.
Secondly, put out a link or a Jsfiddle for us to have something to look at. It is hard to know what is the issue without having anything to debug.